# Prove that norm must be complete

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ be a normed space and $A:X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear map. Show that $A$ is bounded $\iff$ norm $\| \cdot \|_A:=\|x\|_A=\|x\|+\|A(x)\|, \:\: x\in X $ is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction "$\Rightarrow$" should present no problem. (Cauchy in $\Vert\cdot\Vert_A$ implies Cauchy in $\Vert \cdot \Vert$, so there is a $\Vert \cdot \Vert$-limit. Show that this limit is also the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_A$-limit (using boundedness of $A$)).

For the other direction, consider the inclusion

$$
\iota : (X, \Vert \cdot \Vert_A) \rightarrow (X, \Vert\cdot\Vert).
$$

Note that this is a well-defined, linear, continuous, bijective map. By the open mapping theorem, $\iota^{-1}$ is thus bounded (here, we used completeness of $X$ with the usual and with the new norm).

Note that $A' := A : (X, \Vert\cdot\Vert_A) \rightarrow Y$ is bounded (why?), so that $A  = A' \circ \iota^{-1}$ is also bounded.